# Change select tag option in cefsharp winforms

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, scripting, cefsharp

I'm trying to change select tag options using this code in cefsharp

```
Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById(\"REG_CATSEQ\").selectedindex = 1;");
```

This is the select code

```
<select id="REG_CATSEQ"  name="REG_CATSEQ"  class="form-control select2">
                      <option value="">Select a value...</option>
                                                  <option value="1">تسجيل لأول مرة</option>
                                                  <option value="2">الواقعات الحياتية</option>
                                            </select>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex I'd suggest using DevTools to test JavaScript, check for errors etc. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have made a typo. Both languages are case sensitive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

```cs
Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById(\"REG_CATSEQ\").selectedIndex = 1;");
```